# How to validate form post in the controller and also check if the product collection filter matched

Tags: php, magento, collections

I have created a simple product selector. In the phtml, I created a form that post data and these data are received by controller to be validated before registering to a registry.

I also have product collection that gets the data to be filter coming from the registry. I have several filters and if one fails, the system should display a message.

This is what I have done so far.

My Controller:

```
public function indexAction() {
            if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            $data['ta'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueAction');
            $data['tr'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueRequired');
            $data['tm'] = $this->getRequest()->getPost('torqueMetric');
            $data['tmax'] = $data['tr'] / 80 * 100;
            if (validation is equal to true) {
                Mage::register('t-action', $data['ta']);
                Mage::register('t-req', $data['tr']);
                Mage::register('t-metric', $data['tm']);
                Mage::register('t-max', $data['tmax']);
                $this->_redirect('productselector/index/result');
            }else {
                    // Display message about the error
            }
        }
    }
```

My Collection located in the phtml:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldTofilter($attr_name, array(
                'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                ->getAttribute($attr_name)
                                ->getSource()
                                ->getOptionId($attr_val)
                ))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldTofilter($metric, array('gteq' => $metric_val_min))
            ->addFieldTofilter($metric, array('lteq' => $metric_val_max))
            ->load();
if ($collection == NULL) { // not sure how to validate it if one filter fails
    echo "sorry, no product available";
}else {
    //Display some errors
}
```

QUESTIONS:

How to validate form post in the controller and checks if empty and no malicious code?

How to check product collection if one filter was not met?

How do I display these errors from controller and product collection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to validate form post in the controller and checks if empty and no malicious code?

You can check an empty post like this.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('field_name', false)) {
     //yes 'fiel_name' is not empty. do something with it.
}
```

This is because `getPost()` will accept two parameters. If the parameter-1 is not set, then it will return the *default* value that we specified as parameter-2. In this case, default value is `false` and hence condition fails if `field_name` is empty.

I didn't get the "malicious" part in the question. The answer for is, it depends from situation to situation.

> How to check product collection if one filter was not met?

Honestly, question is not clear for me. However if the filters that you have applied using `addFieldToFilter` fails, then you will get an empty collection. You can check the count of a collection like this.

```
if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {
    //do something with collection
} else {
    //show some error
}
```

> How do I display these errors from controller and product collection?

Errors, warning, success messages are setting on session variable and thus you can get the session in the redirecting page and show them in frontend.

These are the avaialble notifications in Magento.

```
$session  = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

//use to show error
$session->addError('add some error message');

//use to show warning
$session->addWarning('add some warning message');

//use to show notice
$session->addNotice('add some notice message');

//use to show success message
$session->addSuccess('add some success message');
```

You can set them in controller. Now this is how you can grab all these items and show in frontend. Use them in the form template wisely.

```
$messages = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages();
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    echo $message;
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev K Tomy for that informative reply. I have a followup question regarding the product collection. Is it good to put the product collection on the phtml or is it better to create a block class and put the collection there? Thanks any way

Comment: @rodge it is a bad practice to put collection on phtml files. You should create a block class and put that collection query in a method and then invoke that method in your template. That is the best practice and do always best practices

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev K Tomy. I have different problem but also related to this question. On the addFieldTofilter($metric, array('lteq' => $metric_val_max)). The product attribute $metric that I am fetching from the database has a data type of varchar so I can't use the relational equation 'lteq' because I am comparing two different data type (integer and varchar). I have separate question and i'll send you the link after 90min. maybe you can help me again. thanks

Comment: Hello @Rajeev K Tomy!  Do you have idea for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708330/magento-how-do-i-run-this-custom-product-attribute-script