# Magento - How do I run this custom product attribute script

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem regarding magento attribute. I have created a custom product input text attribute that supposed to hold an Integer Data Type, however, magento stores it as a varchar. I tried to ask about it here in stackoverflow and they told me that there is no way to change product attribute type to integer from string.

So my solution is to create a custom integer product attribute. I search it on google for several days and I found an article that gives a script that creates a custom attribute. http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.com/2014/03/create-product-attribute.html?showComment=1442885130592#c2319234413343201281

The problem is that I don't know how to run this or use it.

QUESTION:

How do this script run? Can you give me a guide about the step by step process?

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'custom_mprice', array( 
        'input' => 'text',
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Enter Max Price',
        'backend' => '',
        'visible' => 1,
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
        'searchable' => 0,
        'filterable' => 0,
        'sort_order' => 30,
        'comparable' => 0,
        'visible_on_front' => 0,
        'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
        'is_configurable' => 1,
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL, )); 
$installer->endSetup();
```

My goal is to create this attribute in order for me to use it in an arithmetic expression like lesser than or equal to.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collection query look like this.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldTofilter($attr_name, array(
        'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
            ->getAttribute($attr_name)
            ->getSource()
            ->getOptionId($attr_val)
    ))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldTofilter($metric, array('gteq' => $metric_val_min))
    ->addFieldTofilter($metric, array('lteq' => $metric_val_max))
   ->load();
```

The problem that you have described in the question reside in the less than, greater than filtering section.

Here I am showing you an experiment of how you can treat `$metric` as an integer in sql query and thus the query work in your case.

```
//create sql expression
$expr1 = 'CAST (' . $metric . ' AS UNSIGNED) >= ?';
$expr2 = 'CAST (' . $metric . ' AS UNSIGNED) <= ?';
$greaterEqCondtion = new Zend_Db_Expr($expr1);
$lesserEqCondition = new Zend_Db_Expr($expr2);

//applying filters which are relatively simple to express.
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldTofilter($attr_name, array(
        'eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
            ->getAttribute($attr_name)
            ->getSource()
            ->getOptionId($attr_val)
));

//now going to apply filters which is relatively complex in this case.
$collection->getSelect()
    ->where($greaterEqCondtion, $metric_val_min)
    ->where($lesserEqCondition, $metric_val_max);

//we are set, let us load collection
$collection->load();
```

Here `$collection->getSelect()->where()` holds an expression. The expression will make the string value to treat as an integer in the sql query. I didn't test this code. But you can make a try on this.

If you really want to go on with new attribute, then what you need to do is create a new setup resource or use default eav setup resource (`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`). Follow ***[this tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/)*** for how to setup an EAV based model

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev K Tomy for your answer. I have a followup question. Sorry, I'm not really in depth with php, I don't understand this code $greaterEqCondtion = new Zend_Db_Expr($expr1). What does this mean? What I have understand is that this code convert the $metric data coming from the database.

Comment: `Zend_Db_Expr` is a special class which is used to prepare an sql expression in particular. Just remembe this as it will provide you a valid string as ouput. so `$expr`  variable holds an sql expression in string. this expression is defined in such a way that it will treat `$metric` variable as an integer. `$metric` is not coming from database. It is a php variable, that should be defined before collection-loading. particularly `$metric` stands for a data-field.

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev K Tomy. This is the error when I tried the code. a:5:{i:0;s:491:"SELECT `e`.*, `at_product_classification`.`value` AS `product_classification` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_product_classification` ON (`at_product_classification`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_product_classification`.`attribute_id` = '136') AND (`at_product_classification`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE (at_product_classification.value = '7') AND (CAST (max_ft_lbs AS UNSIGNED) >= 1500) AND (CAST (max_ft_lbs AS UNSIGNED) <= 2000)

Comment: continuation: app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)

Comment: this is the condition that is appended by the expression `(CAST (max_ft_lbs AS UNSIGNED) >= 1500) AND (CAST (max_ft_lbs AS UNSIGNED) <= 2000)` . It looks good for me. The conspiracy lies around `max_ft_lbs` field and you need to find out the reason.

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev K Tomy for your help. I'll try to do both solutions.